# Can MySQL calculate totals from a multi-level parent child relationship?

Tags: php, mysql

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume the following tables exist:

### Table 1 - List of Sellers

```
ID |  Parent_ID  |  Percentage
----------------------------
1  |    -        |     .5
2  |    1        |     .4
3  |    2        |     .3
```

This table shows 3 sellers. 1, the main parent, 2, an individual with parent 1 and 3 with parent 2 and super-parent 1. ID 1 gets a 50% commission on all individual sales PLUS the difference in commission for any subagents between their percentage levels.

For example:

The following table would represent a list of sales by Agent:

Table 2 - Sales by Agent

```
ID   |   Cost
-------------
2    |   10.00
2    |   5.00
3    |   9.00
```

In this scenario:

- Seller ID 3 would earn 30% of his sale, or $2.70
- Seller ID 2 would earn 40% of his/her sales (.4 * $5) + (.4 * $10) = $6 PLUS override on his/her child. In this case, he/she earns the difference in commissions plus the amount of the sale (.4 - .3) * $9.00 = $0.90 so Seller ID 2 would earn $6.90 total.
- Seller ID 1 had no individual sales but earns override on his/her child and all subsequents: (.5-.4)*(10.00) + (.5-.4)*(5.00) + (.5-.4)*(9.00) = $2.40

The super parent (ID 1 in this case) could have been the direct parent of ID 3 and earned (.5-.3). This is to say, the parent child relationship is not always linear and there is no set depth to where the hierarchy lay.

Ultimately, I am trying to develop a mysql or php (or combo) formula to determine the what each seller is due in the scenario above. Calculating the total of sales for each seller and the individual seller earnings based on those sales is easy. Figuring out how to apply earning to ID 1 and 2 based on 3's production is another story.

Any prior experience in this area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't make trees easy.

MSSQL has something called common table expressions that make this easier.

With MySQL, the best solution is to use a recursive stored procedure.  But those can be very difficult to get right.

Instead, I would suggest having another table that stores all the parents of a child and how many levels above they are.  This complicates your insertion and deletion code since this table needs to be kept up to date (triggers can help), but it will make your calculations much easier.

Comment: I was just writing the same response. So, +1

Comment: @Alan Geleynse - unfortunately I think your last suggestion is one that doesn't really fit our business needs as we have thousands of these sellers (albeit only on a 5 level schedule). Sellers can change their parent and at times their level as well so keeping all these tables in order along with effective dates won't work. Also - although we **could** code the system to recognize all parents of a new seller when created, it too seems overlyburdensome

Comment: If you are only going to a maximum of 5 levels, you could try doing a recursive stored procedure.  Just make sure you set a limit so you don't end up going beyond the recursion limit.

Comment: @Alan: just a side node: not only SQL Server, but nearly every major database these days has support for recursive queries (Firebird, PostgreSQL, Oracle, DB2, Teradata, SQL Anywhere, H2)

Comment: @Alan Geleynse - can you elaborate on the 'recursive stored procedure'? I am familiar with SP's but have never found anything that leads me to believe even the very, very simple example above is possible

Comment: I think I rethought your initial suggestion but don't feel that initial recursion is the answer (maybe?). I am able to build the hierarchial data including the ID, its parent_ID, the total production of each seller by ID, the depth of the ID relative to the super-parent (in this case ID2 has depth of 1, ID3 has depth of 2, etc) but this still does not get at how to calculate the supplmental earnings of the child nodes as a super-parent.